# Can the variables $n$ and $x$ be separated in estimating $\pi_{n}(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Hardy-Littlewood first conjecture asserts that the number $\pi_{n}(x)$ of prime gaps of size $n$ below $x$ is asymptotic to $2C_{n}\dfrac{x}{\log^2 x}$, where $C_n$ depends only on $n$.

Has it been proven that there exist two functions $f$ and $h$ such that $\pi_{n}(x)=f(n)h(x)+A_{n}(x)\sim f(n)h(x)$? If so, writing $x+O(1)=\sum_{n=2}^{G(x)}n(f(n)h(x)+A_{n}(x))$, where $G(x)$ is the maximal prime gap below $x$, would it be possible to get an unconditional upper bound for $G(x)$ in terms of $h(x)$?

My idea is that the different error terms $A_{n}(x)$ cancel out up to a bounded quantity when summed over $n$.

Comment: $\pi_{n}(x)\sim f(n)h(x)$ means $|\pi_{n}(x)-f(n)h(x)|\le C_n(x) h(x)$ with $C_n(x) \to 0$. What do you get from that and $p-1 = \sum_{n \le G(p)} n \pi_n(p)$.

Comment: I guess you meant $p-2$? I get $p-2=\sum_{n\leq G(p)}nh(p)(f(n)+C_{n}(p))$ but I don't see where this leads.

Comment: Sure it doesn't lead anywhere because $C_n(x)$ depends on $n$.